# Remove extra scroll-space at right side in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a header tag like

```
h1 {
    background: url('../welcome_page/resources/images/welcome-logo.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 100000;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #4775A3;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: black;
}
```

in my html page. This creates extra space at right-hand side. Can anyone suggest to remove the extra-space in the right side ??

Answer (score 0):

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

h1 {
    background: url('../welcome_page/resources/images/welcome-logo.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 100000;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #4775A3;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

### Heading

Comment: I already added like html {
    overflow: auto;
    border: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

Comment: Well! I think now working perfectly! See: https://jsfiddle.net/43br6ex5/

Comment: html {
    overflow: auto;
    border: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
h1 {
    color:white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin: auto; 
    z-index: 100000;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #4775A3;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: black;
}

Comment: can you modify in this css ?

Comment: html { overflow-x: hidden;border: 0px;height: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;} 
body { margin: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;color: #000000;background-repeat: repeat-x;
} h1 {color: white;position: absolute;top: 0px;margin: auto;z-index: 100000;width: 100%;padding-top: 30px;text-align: left;padding-left: 150px;height: 80px;background-color: #4775A3;border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-color: black;
}

Comment: Just add `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: Hi everyone, I have got solution for this, I have inserted text tag inside the h1 tag, the css is : h1 {
 background: url('../icons/welcome-logo.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
 color:white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 100000;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 text-align: left;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #4775A3;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: black;
}

text{
 padding-left: 150px;
}

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
< h1>< text>XXX  </text ></h1 >
```

### CSS

```
h1 {
background: url('../icons/welcome-logo.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
color:white;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
margin: auto;
z-index: 100000;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 30px;
text-align: left;
height: 80px;
background-color: #4775A3;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: black;
}

text{
    padding-left: 150px;
}
```